# Import CER file into NTAuth Store on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, certificate

I have to import a third-party CER file into the NTAuth Store on a Windows 2003 server. I followed the Microsoft documentation as described at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295663, but I received an error message "Access denied".

Can anyone let me know the required permissions to perform this?

Answer (score 1):

Membership in **Enterprise Admins**, or equivalent, is the minimum required to complete this procedure.

[Add Published Certificates to Active Directory Containers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731612.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)